# How to create nuget package for native C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I want to publish package about sdl_mixer, it's a native package. I did as [tutorial](https://docs.nuget.org/Create/using-a-gui-to-build-packages) said. I put `.dll` `.h`and `.lib` files into ***package content***, but the final package didn't work. So what is right way to create c++ nuget package?

Another question: I found in nuget, most native c++ package are published in two packages, for example:

> sdl2_ttf.v140
>
> sdl2_ttf.v140.redist

What is difference between those two files? And how can I publish my packages like that?

---

**Update:**

I followed the [tutorial](https://docs.nuget.org/Create/using-a-gui-to-build-packages) on how to publish native packages. I have written the following `autopkg file`

```
nuget{
    nuspec {
        id = MySdl_mixer;
        version :2.0.0.0;
        title: sdl mixer;
        authors: { Sam Lantinga, Stephane Peter, Ryan Gordon};
        owners: {spartawhy117};
        licenseUrl: "http://libsdl.org/license.php";
        projectUrl: "http://libsdl.org/index.php";
        iconUrl:"";
        requireLicenseAcceptance:false;
        summary:Nothing;
        description: @"SDL_mixer is a sample multi-channel audio mixer library.... 
    ";
       releaseNotes: "Release of C++ ";
       copyright:Copyright 2015;
       tags: {v140 ,sdl_mixer , native, CoApp };
};

    files {
        #defines {
            Include = include\;
            Bin = bin64\;
            Lib = lib64\;
        }

        include:{"${Include}*"};

        [x64,v140,debug,desktop]{
            lib: ${Lib}SDL2_mixer.lib;
            bin: ${Bin}SDL2_mixer.dll；
        }
        [x64,v140,release,desktop]{
            lib: ${Lib}SDL2_mixer.lib;
            bin: ${Bin}SDL2_mixer.dll；
        }
     };
    targets {
            Defines += HAS_SDLMIXER;
     };
}
```

Running the command `Write-NuGetPackage .\sdl_mixer.autopkg` returns an error unexpected input of the end. What is the problem here?

Comment: "didn't work" does not tell much... what is the issue? nothing gets installed, runtime errors occur, components are missing?

Comment: @dlatikay when I want to include the .h file , it remind me can't find the head file .

Comment: Can you make sure you didn't miss "}" at the end of your autopkg file? The error indicate that the autopkg file content is incorrect.

Comment: Do you know how to add multiple macros to targets? like
`Defines += HAS_SDLMIXER;HAS_B`

Comment: For Visual C/C++ Nuget Packages look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740881/create-nuget-package-from-unmanaged-c-c-code-in-visual-studio-solution-and-p

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Nuget package for C++/C Visual Studio Solution projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740881/create-nuget-package-for-c-c-visual-studio-solution-projects)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I searched around for days until I found there is really no help out there on the internet at all. I did managed to piece together how to do it, and through trial and error got it working well. Which I have documented here:

https://digitalhouseblog.wordpress.com/2019/08/22/how-to-make-a-nuget-package-for-c/

But I'll summarize here anyways:

- Gather or stage your native library files into a folder of your
  choosing.
- Create a *.nuspec file in that folder.
- Edit the *.nuspec file to include the files you want to include in your package.
- Create a *.props file
- Call nuget pack to create the package.
- Push the nuget package to a feed somewhere.
- Create a packages.config file.
- Edit the visual studio project file to import the *.props file

Notice that the nuget tools inside the visual studio IDE are NEVER used. You have to do a LOT manually. See the link for full details and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CoApp PowerShell tools](http://coapp.org/pages/releases.html) to create the Native Nuget packages easily.

> **Creating Native Packages**
>
> If you’re interested in publishing your
> native libraries via NuGet, you can choose to create the NuGet
> packages manually. However, there’s an easier way--the CoApp project
> volunteered to write C++ oriented tools to create NuGet packages, and
> they have released a beta version of their tools. These tools simplify
> the process of generating the MSBuild files and NuGet packages from
> existing header and library files--you just need to create a
> configuration script to describe the contents of the package and then
> run the tools to generate the NuGet package.

Refer to this link for more detailed information: [Support for Native Projects.](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/support-for-native-projects)

Comment: CoApp powershell isn't supported anymore. No support of VS2015 and 2017.

Comment: That link at docs.nuget.org is worthless. Doesn't explain how to do it all, just that it can be done. Still looking for examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this from **Visual Studio** C++ using a Visual Studio Solution and projects.
Look at my answer here.

[Create Nuget package for C++/C Visual Studio Solution projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740881/create-nuget-package-from-unmanaged-c-c-code/65996134#65996134)

The above question seems to be Linux.

Comment: [Link-only answers are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/248627) as they low-effort and low-value. If this is a duplicate question, please flag it as such.

Comment: Yes, you are "pointing at an answer", which makes it a link-only answer as I stated in my previous comment. Such answers are discouraged here, and routinely deleted. Please read [the link I provided](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/248627), which says in part, 'When someone goes on Stack Exchange, the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer.'