# Create a nuget package for Visual C++

Tags: c#, c++, nuget, package

I have a Visual C++ project on Visual Studio. Is it possible to create a nugget package automatically with each build with that?

I have tried installing OctoPack nuget package for example which creates a nuget package on build. 
This works flawlessly for my C# projects and therefore it automatically creates nuget packages.

However for my Visual C++ it produces error on installation.

```
Executing script file '<<PROJECT>>\packages\OctoPack.3.6.3\tools\Install.ps1'...
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

At <<PROJECT>>\packages\OctoPack.3.6.3\tools\Install.ps1:15 char:79
+ ... orts | Where-Object { $_.Project.EndsWith($package.Id + '.targets') }
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Do you know how one can create nuget packages in C++? While there are very nice guides on the internet for creating nuget packages for C# projects, and nugget packages that do that automatically for you, I couldn't find anything for Visual C++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create nuget package for native C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728583/how-to-create-nuget-package-for-native-c)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Nuget package for C++/C Visual Studio Solution projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740881/create-nuget-package-for-c-c-visual-studio-solution-projects)

Answer (score 0):

I myself had this same question. I found no satisfactory answers in one place. So once I figured it out, I wrote up an extensive blog detailing how to do it here:
https://digitalhouseblog.wordpress.com/2019/08/22/how-to-make-a-nuget-package-for-c/